# Hashcat bruteforce define digit range form and to

Tags: brute-force, hashcat

I know this password is between 90,000,000 and 500,000,000

how can I tell hashcat to bruteforce exactly in that range? I mean starting from 90,000,000 and ending at 500,000,000

I go the password doing this, but is so inefficient! I would like to know the proper way

```
./hashcat64.bin --hash-type 2500 --attack-mode 3 ~/Desktop/wifi.hccapx ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d

./hashcat64.bin --hash-type 2500 --attack-mode 3 ~/Desktop/wifi.hccapx ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by bruteforcing between 90000000 and 99999999:

```
./hashcat64.bin --hash-type 2500 --attack-mode 3 ~/Desktop/wifi.hccapx 9?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
```

Then let's bruteforce from 100000000 to 499999999:

```
./hashcat64.bin --hash-type 2500 --attack-mode 3 ~/Desktop/wifi.hccapx -1 1234 ?1?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
```

Finally, let's try 500000000:

```
./hashcat64.bin --hash-type 2500 --attack-mode 3 ~/Desktop/wifi.hccapx 500000000
```

Comment: Additional optimization: all three of these can be put into a single mask file, so that you only have to run hashcat once.